# Remove language code from url

Tags: joomla-3.x, language, falang

I'm having a slight issue with a multi language site. I am using FaLang to handle translations of 4 languages (*English, Spanish, French and Italian*) on a 3.3.6 Joomla installation with *English* set as the **default** site language.

I have enabled the *"Remove URL Language Code"* in the language filter. When viewing the site in **English** my url's look like this

```
www.example.com/company/contact.html
```

And the language switcher shows the other languages like so:

```
www.example.com/es/company/contact.html
www.example.com/fr/company/contact.html
www.example.com/it/company/contact.html
```

My issue is that if I change the language to either of the other 3, my English URL's looks like this in the language switcher:

```
www.example.com/en/company/contact.html
```

When clicking on the link one is redirected with a 303 from `.../en/...` to `.../...`.

As far as I know that is the intent of Joomla, but I'd like to remove the `/en/` from my English URL's, so that when showing my website in any of the languages my English URL's look like this:

```
www.example.com/company/contact.html
```

I am using FaLang's language switcher but also experience this "issue" with Joomla's own language switcher / translation system.

I don't use any SEF components and haven't found any which could solve this, I believe I have to change something in the core routing of Joomla but alas I don't know where or what.

.htaccess as per request

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: man before anything else - I read: Joomla 3.3.6 - forget anything else you do and simply go and update Joomla. anything below 3.4.7 is hugely vulnerable. If you can't update, then at least install the latest Admin Tools Pro as temporary solution, which contains firewall protection against the recent J vulnerability.

Comment: @FFrewin I have Admin tools pro installed, and planning to upgrade to 3.4.8 in the near future, however, it still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: The comment was not intented to solve the issue - just to trigger your attention about the outdated and insecure joomla version you are running.

Comment: @FFrewin I realise now that I didn't formulate it properly, I ment that upgrading to 3.4.8 didn't / won't solve the issue. None the less, I appreciate the heads up.

Comment: As per your issue, when you say your english url, you mean the underlying href value of the language flag link? Does it redirect to the normal url though? Is it the core language switcher module? Are you using any SEF component?

Comment: No SEF components, and yes, the underlying href value of the language flag, it first redirect to the /en/ part but then redirects to without and shows as it should. No, I'm using FaLang, but the core switcher module does the same.

Comment: Are you using Apache as web server?

Comment: @fruppel Yes, Apache 2.2.22

Comment: Did you already try to rewrite your URLs with mod_rewrite? I'm not an expert but you should be able to specify rules which redirect all www.example.com/en/[...] domains to www.example.com/[..]

Comment: @fruppel As stated in the question, the URL's are redirected on `/en/` to without, that is not the issue, the issue is that Joomla is showing it in the first place.

Comment: I don't think that it will still show the /en/ part if you set up a redirect rule in your htaccess file. I would just give it a try.

Comment: @fruppel I have a redir rule in my .htaccess that does this, further more, a .htaccess file does not modify the URL itself, it can redirect it and change the end result, but not the "incoming" url itself.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the relevant content of the htaccess file please?

Comment: @fruppel I will, but this is **not** a .htaccess issue, this is not about redirecting to the correct end result, as the end result is correct, but simply about removing the `/en/` part from the URL when showing the website in a different language than the default.

Comment: @fruppel, this is not related to htaccess. The redirection occurs anyhow from Joomla itself. The thing here is the generated SEF urls from Joomla. Edopax got a point with this, as it would make sense to want to have the final url, instead of the one that it will be redirected to. Now, edomax maybe this could be possible by modifying directly the mod_languages and do string replacements in the urls if the /en part is found. Maybe it's worth checking this to see how it goes. Hopefully Joomla will make it to understand that you are switching languages and no futther issues arrive.

Comment: Ok at least my understanding of rewriterules improved. How about the option "Remove URL Language Code" in the language filter plugin? At least its description says that the language code for your default language will be removed from URLs

Comment: @fruppel Not to be rude, but did you read the question? The second line says _"I have enabled the "Remove URL Language Code" in the language filter."_

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Ok I see, the problem seems to be in the languagefilter plugin, starting with line 183. If your current language is not equal to the default language the language code is added, no matter if you set the remove option in the plugin or not. And like Bakual answered, that is needed to tell Joomla to change the language. So maybe there is really no way to do this.

Comment: @fruppel As mentioned in my comments to Bakual's answer, I believe that it's a matter of telling Joomla that if no language is defined in the URL, then switch over to English, for some there might be a issue / argument that it would cause issues for the automatic redirect when a user has a cookie that says the language should be shown in French (or some other language), but in my case, it wouldn't be a issue. - In a simplified way: `$lang = (empty($urlLangTag)) ? 'en' : $urlLangTag;`

Comment: yes but even if you set the language filter so that it doesn't use the default language prefix, the language switcher module STILL uses it!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know what you want isn't possible.
The /en/ is needed so Joomla knows that you want to change the language. Because with www.example.com/company/contact.html Joomla would look in your language cookie and redirect to the currently active language.
So for changing languages, you need to explicitely tell Joomla that you want to switch to english. Once english is active, the links should be without /en/.

Comment: I figured as much, but I have a feeling that it should be possible to tell Joomla that if there is no `/en/` (Or any of the other language tags in the url) present then it should set the language to English.

Comment: @Epodax, hi Epodax, I didn't continue on our previous comments discussion although I had a further look at this. I also came with a similar conclusion like the one Bakual wrote above. Despite I would also like to have the urls in such cases without the language code, for now this seems not possible, or at least not something obvious or easy to achieve. I may guess you are considering it SEO wise, but at the end I think it won't really hurt. But that was a good catch. I haven't ever noticed that previously.

Comment: @FFrewin Sadly this was also the conclusion that I came to myself when trying to solve it, I haven't tried to make any changes to the JRoute yet as I've never tried to alter core files yet, but also because I'm reluctant to modify core files. Although I believe that it should be possible as per my logic the site knows that the default language is "English" and should set the language according if no language is defined in the URL. - I will keep trying to find a soloution.

Comment: Don't look at the router. Look at the language filter plugin. This is where this is done. See https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/plugins/system/languagefilter/languagefilter.php#L234
You could create your own plugin to avoid hacking core files.

Comment: Unfortunately, replacing the language filter plugin is not possible as the use of joomlas own languagefilter plugin is hard coded into the cms-code (in libraries/cms/application/site.php). So you really do need to hack the core to make this happen.

Comment: The 'en' thing is not really needed for Joomla to know you want the english version, this can be set in the menu. The fact is that Joomla does not recognize this automatically, but it should.

Answer (score 1):

2020: It is possible. Just go to Language Filter plugin, configuration. "Remove URL Language Code" to "Yes".

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for contributing, @Zibi. Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Right now what you request is not possible. I find this behavior very annoying and I will send a pull request to Joomla developers to change this.

Meanwhile, you can use the redirect functionality to redirect your pages. For example, let's say that you have a page httx://yoursite.com/en/products.html, but you want to use the url httx://yoursite.com/products.html, then you have to create a redirection url in the Redirect Extension from /products.html to /en/products.html. The bad thing is that you must do this for every url you want to remove the language suffix..

I think too, this should be automatically calculated by Joomla.